# Comparing array of keys of associative array to integer indexed array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have written the following code to check whether an array is associative or not

```
function is_associative( $arr ) {
    $arr = array_keys( $arr );
    return $arr != array_keys( $arr );
}
```

It returns true for arrays like:

```
array("a" => 5,"b" => 9);
```

and false for numeric arrays

But it doesn't return true for associative arrays with single element like:

```
array("a" =>9);
```

Why does it returns false for associative arrays with single element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `!==` in your comparison:

```
return $arr !== array_keys( $arr );
```

This generates the [correct output](http://viper-7.com/cyiiTG) of both of them being true.

Otherwise type juggling will consider the values for the single element array as equal:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "a" } 
array(1) { [0]=> int(0) }
```

Here, `"a" == 0` is true (as "a" is silently cast to 0), but `"a" === 0` is false.

Comment: Why they aren't of the same type when it is single element array ?

Comment: @JinuJD - I've updated my answer with a more clear description of what's going on